# How to exit time_delay loop w/ key press in C?

Tags: c, timer, infinite-loop, timedelay

My program is reading ADC values through 7 different channels.  I have a timer set up which reads each channel sequentially.  I would like to run this timer infinitely (but right now I have it set for an hour) and be able to exit the timer with a key press (q for example).  I have to insert both an if and while loop looking for getchar()==q, but each loop would pause the program until I actually pressed q then it would read the next line and repeat.  I would appreciate if anyone can help me exit the timer on a key press.  Thanks

```
static void ch0
{
    send_receive_LTC1859 (0x00, 0x00, 0, spifd);
}

//Here CH 1-6 go (saving space for readers)

static void ch7
{
    send_receive_LTC1859 (0xF0, 0x08, 0, spifd);    
    printf("\n");

//Look for quit key
}

uint32 accel_testing (){

    spifd = fopen("spi2:", 0);
    printf("Accel names\n");

    MQX_TICK_STRUCT ticks;
    MQX_TICK_STRUCT dticks;
    _timer_id       read_ch0;
    _timer_id       read_ch2;
    _timer_id       read_ch3;
    _timer_id       read_ch4;
    _timer_id       read_ch5;
    _timer_id       read_ch6;
    _timer_id       read_ch7;

    _timer_create_component(TIMER_TASK_PRIORITY, TIMER_STACK_SIZE);
    _time_init_ticks(&dticks, 0);
    _time_add_msec_to_ticks(&dticks,500);

    _time_get_elapsed_ticks(&ticks);
    read_ch0 = _timer_start_periodic_at_ticks(ch0, 0, 
       TIMER_ELAPSED_TIME_MODE, &ticks, &dticks);
    _time_add_msec_to_ticks(&ticks, 5);
    read_ch2 = _timer_start_periodic_at_ticks(ch2, 0, 
       TIMER_ELAPSED_TIME_MODE, &ticks, &dticks);
    _time_add_msec_to_ticks(&ticks, 5);
    read_ch3 = _timer_start_periodic_at_ticks(ch3, 0, 
       TIMER_ELAPSED_TIME_MODE, &ticks, &dticks);
    _time_add_msec_to_ticks(&ticks, 5);
    read_ch4 = _timer_start_periodic_at_ticks(ch4, 0, 
       TIMER_ELAPSED_TIME_MODE, &ticks, &dticks);
    _time_add_msec_to_ticks(&ticks, 5);
    read_ch5 = _timer_start_periodic_at_ticks(ch5, 0, 
       TIMER_ELAPSED_TIME_MODE, &ticks, &dticks);
    _time_add_msec_to_ticks(&ticks, 5);
    read_ch6 = _timer_start_periodic_at_ticks(ch6, 0, 
       TIMER_ELAPSED_TIME_MODE, &ticks, &dticks);
    _time_add_msec_to_ticks(&ticks, 5);
    read_ch7 = _timer_start_periodic_at_ticks(ch7, 0, 
       TIMER_ELAPSED_TIME_MODE, &ticks, &dticks);
    _time_add_msec_to_ticks(&ticks, 5);

    _time_delay(3600000); // wait 1 hour
    printf("\nThe task is finished!\n");

    _timer_cancel(read_ch0);
    _timer_cancel(read_ch2);
    _timer_cancel(read_ch3);
    _timer_cancel(read_ch4);
    _timer_cancel(read_ch5);
    _timer_cancel(read_ch6);
    _timer_cancel(read_ch7);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on linux then `select()` will help.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
int
input_timeout (int filedes, unsigned int seconds)
{
  fd_set set;
  struct timeval timeout;
  /* Initialize the file descriptor set. */
  FD_ZERO (&set);
  FD_SET (filedes, &set);

  /* Initialize the timeout data structure. */
  timeout.tv_sec = seconds;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;

  /* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
  return TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY (select (FD_SETSIZE,
                                     &set, NULL, NULL,
                                     &timeout));
}
int
main (void)
{
  fprintf (stdin, "select returned %d.\n",
           input_timeout (STDIN_FILENO, 5));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is outright astonishing since you seem to use Frescale's MQX APIs?

Comment: Yea unfortunately I am not supplied with Linux for this project.

Comment: @Socci See Porting issue on this http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/select.3.asp It says select() will not work in windoiws95 in all other version of windows it will work so go on.....